# Individual wheels' toes are out of range but combination is within specs

Tags: chevrolet, wheels, steering, alignment

[image]I went to have my 1999 Chevy Tahoe aligned after getting new tires mounted.  I am concerned about the toe results.  The left front toe is 0.37, specified to be 0.02-0.22; the right is -0.5, with same spec of 0.02-0.22; and the total is 0.32, specified 0.04-0.44.

Should I be concerned with the left toe, even though the total is in range?

Comment: Looks like the _both_ wheels are out of spec, yes? One clarification: are these values the _after_-alignment values, or did you just have the measurement done, and not the work yet?

Comment: Post a picture of the alignment printout

Comment: Some of the numbers are cut off in the picture. Can you fix that?

Comment: Also why are there no caster readings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, total toe is what matters, as long as your steering wheel is straight when you are riding down the road. Basically when those readings were taken the steering wheel may not have been pointing straight ahead. If the tech didn't still have the steering wheel locked down and the steering wheel turned slightly it would cause those readings.

Another possible cause is the alignment is compensating for a thrust angle problem, if so again this would be normal. I can expand on my answer if you will include a picture of the printout you got. You can black out VIN, name, address, etc if it's on there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced its ok.  The total toe is within spec but the toe on one side is out of spec, this would mean that the wheel may well scrub on one edge faster than the rest. The idea of it being acceptable at 0.44 is that its a total of 0.22 on both sides.  The front left is 0.37 out which is out of spec.  I would normally bring it back to within spec.